# js variable value into Web Sql db

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-sql

I cannot find a solution for passing JS variable value (text) into websql DB ..
All i keep finding is some PHP solutions and I do not want to use it.

```
function store(){
    var x = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
    names.push(x);
    L10();
    $('#tt').text(names);
}


function Insert(){
    db.transaction(function(t){
    t.executeSql('INSERT INTO Followers(fNAME) VALUES (?)',[x]);//->here is my problem :) x variable
    });
}
$('#inp2').click(function(){

    store();

    Insert();
});
```

Comment: can you post the code when calling store() and Insert()?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: var x gets the value from my input field

Comment: I would need to store value from my variable to web sql DB

Comment: getting : ReferenceError: x is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error ,I used private variable x instead of global x  .. duh!

```
x = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
```